# How to access the title of the selected part of a segmented control from another class?

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol, swift4

In my first view controller, I have the segmented control. I am trying to get the string value of the title of the selected part of the segmented control from my second view controller. Anyone have any idea on how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You've probably got downvotes because you haven't given any code or described what you have tried. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any code written, but I presume that this is a present and dismiss view controller scenario, not `addchildviewcontroller` or `addsubview`. In that case there are lots of ways to do it, here are two:

1) Make a global variable that detects the status of segmented control.

```
@IBOutlet weak var segContoll: UISegmentedControl!
func back() {
globalvar = segContoll.titleForSegment(at: segContoll.selectedSegmentIndex)
}
```

2) Make a protocol, here is what it should look like:

```
protocol NotifyDelegate {
    func collectionViewSelectedIndex(indexPath : Int)
}

class CollectionViewForSessions: ... {
    var delegate: NotifyDelegate?
func ... {
//The nextview delegate
    sessionCollection.delegate = self
}
    func ... {
//Instead of inputing a number, customize it to input a string segContoll.titleForSegment(at: segContoll.selectedSegmentIndex)
        delegate?.collectionViewSelectedIndex(indexPath: indexPath.row)
    }
}

class MessagesWithPerson: NotifyDelegate {
    func collectionViewSelectedIndex(indexPath: Int) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm quite sure you are supposed to declare a global variable by simply declaring a variable outside of any class, structure or protocol, not by using 'globalvar'. Also, when I declare the global variable outside of my class, it gives the error message "Instance member 'nameOfSegControl' cannot be used on type 'viewControllerSegControlIsIn'.

Comment: My original message was intended to be perceived as a blueprint. Clearly, you need to implement this outside of your class: `var yourString: String!` and assign it in your back func, where you dismiss the view: `segContoll.titleForSegment(at: segContoll.selectedSegmentIndex)`